# Doctrine collection criteria isNull

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, orm, frameworks

I have an User entity, and I try join it with manytomany relation to UserGroup. It works fine, but i try filtering the joined entities, because I use for example a softdelete field.

```
class User
{
    // ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\UserBundle\Entity\UserGroup")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="users_groups",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     * )
     */
    protected $groups;

    public function getGroups()
    {
        return $this->groups->matching(Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->isNull('te.deleted_at')));
    }

    // ...
}
```

The problem: If the criteria contains any null value, the doctrine don't use that for the sql query. It's mean, in this example, the SELECT statement dont containts any "deleted_at IS NULL" in where.

I found the reason, because doctrine filter it in the SqlValueVisitor.php

```
if (($operator === Comparison::EQ || $operator === Comparison::IS) && $value === null) {
    return;
} else if ($operator === Comparison::NEQ && $value === null) {
    return;
}
```

Ok, but what is the solution for this problem? Or if I use doctrine2, i can't filter the null fields?

I know, i can use doctrine filters, but i dont want, because in my case (and in this example) its simple, but i build this filter from code dinamicly.

Comment: You should be looking at the `ClosureExpressionVisitor` when filtering collections, not the `SqlValueVisitor`. Your getter has nothing to do with the executed SQL query (the SQL fetch gets triggered by the getter in the proxy class before you code even gets called), if you want to issue a custom query to fetch your entity you have to implement that in a custom repository class.

Comment: Sorry, but I dont understand, because if i change the isnull for example to ->gt('te.id','1') then the SQL query will contains this criteria. So the question is, why not constains it the isnull criteria, or how can i put any IS NULL to sql, like ->gt or any another criteria? In ->gt the query output is: `SELECT te.name AS name, te.roles AS roles, te.id AS id, te.created_at AS created_at, te.updated_at AS updated_at, te.deleted_at AS deleted_at, te.undeletable AS undeletable FROM user_group te JOIN users_groups t ON t.group_id = te.id WHERE t.user_id = ? AND te.id > ?`

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, you just can't use `Criteria::expr()->isNull()` with ManyToMany relationships. There a couple of long standing issues in the doctrine/orm GitHub repository regarding this - [1](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/7717), [2](https://github.com/doctrine/orm/issues/5644).

As a workaround, you can manually filter out the null values like this:

```php
$this->groups->filter(function ($group) {
    return null === $group->getDeletedAt();
});
```

Though you must note, that this will load **all** the Users UserGroups from the database and pass them each through the filter function. As opposed to the `->matching()` approach which builds an SQL query and will not load any UserGroups which have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
public function getGroups()
{
    return $this->groups->matching(Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->neq('deleted_at', null)));
}
```

Comment: It works only if I use EAGER (if I dont, it will return all groups), and the sql query dont contains it just php side filtered. So it dont work :(

Comment: @esemve filtering of the relation can not be done inside one sql query. I mean you can't select users and usergroups at the same time with filtering usergroups, because this will filter users too. so either you filter it on php side, or make 2 queries first one select users, second select non-deleted usergroups of selected users.